# create VIEW in mysql from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, dovecot

I have a table with users for my mail server. This table for imap authenication in dovecot:

```
+-------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------+------+---------------------------------------+--------+---------+---------------------------+
| user_name   | domain_name      | passwd            | pwd_hash         | uid  | gid  | mailbox_basepath                      | enable | quota   | desc_rec                  |
+-------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------+------+---------------------------------------+--------+---------+---------------------------+
| logistic    | piduna.pp.ua     | loG-1990M         | _no_hash_passwd_ | 2000 | 2000 | /home/maildir/piduna.pp.ua/           |      1 | 2048000 | box for logistic          |
| 1c          | piduna.pp.ua     | 1c_user_1c        | _no_hash_passwd_ | 2000 | 2000 | /home/maildir/piduna.pp.ua            |      1 | 2048000 | Denisyuk V.V.             |
| admin       | piduna.pp.ua     | AAddMmM1N         | _no_hash_passwd_ | 2000 | 2000 | /home/maildir/piduna.pp.ua            |      1 | 2048000 | Admin                     |
| al.service  | piduna.pp.ua     | Alumo_Serv4321    | _no_hash_passwd_ | 2000 | 2000 | /home/maildir/piduna.pp.ua            |      1 | 2048000 | Alumo Service             |
```

I need to create table with two columns. First column, all@piduna.pp.ua. Second column it is all my email accounts. In one table, I know how make concatenation from user_name and domain_name. Look:

```
CREATE VIEW `forwardings_all_view` AS select lcase(concat(`users`.`user_name`,'@',`users`.`domain_name`)) AS `email_fqn` from `users` where (`users`.`enable` = 1)
```

But, how to add in it VIEW, second column: all@piduna.pp.ua.

Like that:

```
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| email_fqn                    | source                                          | 
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| .logistic@piduna.pp.ua       | all@piduna.pp.ua                                | 
| 1c@piduna.pp.ua              |                                                 | 
| admin@piduna.pp.ua           |                                                 |
| al.service@piduna.pp.ua      |                                                 |
```

Comment: Where is the data for the second column coming from?

Comment: i think, that i need create second table. with column name 'source'. and with data in it column: all@piduna.pp.ua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create view first_user as
select user_name from users where enable limit 1;

create view forwardings_all_view as
select lcase(concat(a.`user_name`,'@',a.`domain_name`)) AS `email_fqn`,
  if(b.user_name is null, '', 'all@piduna.pp.ua') `source`
from `users` a
left join first_user b on a.user_name = b.user_name
where a.`enable` = 1;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfe045/1)

Comment: thats good. But i want in 'col2' to have one field with all@piduna.pp.ua, but withoout a lot fields.

Comment: not all. i need one data field. in second column. in your example, i have many data fields all@piduna.pp.ua

Comment: can you post an example of the view you want? I think our definitions of `column` are different.

Comment: ok. i changed that question. please look. thanks for you help

Comment: thanks, but i have that: ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: maybe my problem has easy decision. i need two columns. in first, all@piduna.pp.ua. in second, all my email accounts.

Comment: i guess mysql doesn't like views containing subqueries. try the updated answer

Comment: Sorry Fabricator. You lost a lot of time. But, I have: ERROR 1351 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Comment: no problem. i set up an auxiliary view `first_user`. it should work now.